# React Native: Setting state/passing data between sibling screens

Tags: react-native

I have a root component named 'Initial' which is responsible for rendering siblings screens 'LoginScreen' and 'HomeScreen' (Which is a drawerNavigator).

On LoginScreen I am performing validation and getting response such as (Name and Image). I want to set the name and image in drawerNavigator from this response in LoginScreen.

Whats the best way to acheive this without using redux?
[image]

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the data through navigation params. read here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

But the proper solution for this is to use a state management framework such as redux or mobx. I would suggest mobx since its much simpler. read this https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-with-mobx-getting-started-ba7e18d8ff44

but there is a hack way of doing this. you can have a singleton object which will hold this information in app memory which you can use across your components.

'Settings.js'

```
const Settings = {
  userName: "",
  avatar: "", // default avatar if you need

  getName() {
    return this.userName;
  },
  setName(userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  },
  getAvatar() {
    return this.getAvatar;
  },
  setAvatar(avatarUrl) {
    this.avatar = avatarUrl;
  },

  initalizeData() {
    // make a http call to the server or
    // fetch it from local storage
    // and do
    // this.setName(name)
    // this.setAvatar(url)
  }
};

module.exports = Settings;
```

Init.js

```
export default class Init extends Component<Props> {

      componentWillMount(){
         //Settings.initalizeData() // if fetching from server or local storage 
         Settings.setName('John Doe')
      }


 }
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
const Settings = require("../Settings");


export default class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
     console.log('Name',Settings.getName())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```